# How to calculate air velocity from wire resistance?

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to construct a constant current hot wire anemometer. For this, resistance is the input of the Arduino. There is a relationship between wire resistance and air velocity.

How can I calculate velocity from wire resistance?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but I am not sure how Arduino related this is, apart for you are using an Arduino. I think that you would get a better  response by asking a separate, non-Arduino related question on SE Physics first, to get an equation to use. Once you have that, then, maybe, come back here to ask how to put that equation/formula into an Arduino sketch.

Comment: Do you already have an equation? If so, edit your question to include it. What research have you done so far? What code do you already have? What is not working, exactly?

Comment: OK You have a theory, test it.  Its not going to take much to hook a wire up to an analog port and measure the changes in resistance.  You are probably only going to get minute changes so you will need to alter the other parameters to cater for it, and its possible that they might be outside the limits of what an Arduino can handle.

Comment: I think that, for this to work, you also need to measure the ambient temperature. You also need the temperature to resistance curve of the wire you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple really, all you need to do is code the equations on this page and then supply some heat and you will be able to do it.  Just remember integer division rounds down :)

http://www-g.eng.cam.ac.uk/whittle/current-research/hph/hot-wire/hot-wire.html